# AngularJS - keeping url parameters on redirect

Tags: angularjs

I'm currently playing with angularjs and trying to interface with a secondary site - Strava. This requires that I send a request off to their site with a redirect url and they stick an extra parameter in the redirected url. However, im having some problems getting this to work with a basic angular view controller structure.

My app currently does a redirect from index.html to show view1 in the following way

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.otherwise({
       redirectTo: '/view1'
});

}])
```

So this is always redirecting to show view1 when the browser hits index.html for example.

The url that i get back from the third party is as follows (the url i send them plus the code parameter)

```
http://mydomain:myport/index.html?code=12345678
```

but as this hits my route provider, it gets redirected to

```
http://mydomain:myport/index.html?code=12345678#/view1
```

The problem then is that in my view1 controller i try to do the following

```
.controller('View1Ctrl',  ['$scope','$routeParams', function($scope,$routeParams) {
  console.log($routeParams.code);
}]);
```

and the code parameter is unavailable. If i manually change the url to

```
http://mydomain:myport/index.html#/view1?code=12345678
```

Then the code parameter is available. Its almost if the parameter is only available to the view if it's specified after the #/view part of the url.

Does anyone know what I need to do to get this working correctly.

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable `html5Mode` :

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true, 
            requireBase: false
        });
```

> https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

The `$location` *service* parses the *URL* in the browser address bar (based on window.location) and makes the URL available to your application. Changes to the URL in the address bar are reflected into the `$location` service and changes to `$location` are reflected into the browser address bar.

Comment: I added this and it now redirects to a url with the extra parameter missing. I think i need to add a 'when' clause to my routeprovider to retain the parameter?

Comment: Yes!
`$routeProvider.when('/page1', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/page1.ejs', 
            controller: 'page1Controller'
        });`
see this: http://pastebin.com/9QZysp5D